# How to add the #include file into the Tanuki wrapper using Maven appassembler-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, deployment, tanuki

The [Tanuki wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-directives.html) allows you to override the configuration using the property

```
#include ../conf/wrapper-settings.conf
```

I am using maven to generate the jsw config and I can't see a way in the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-jsw.html) to add the following line

```
#include ../conf/wrapper-settings.conf
```

to the wrapper.{app}.conf file

Perhaps a bit of background as maybe this is not the best approach
I want to create a number of launch scripts for each environment 
So say for SIT I want to have sit-small, sit-med, sit-large, sit (default extra large)
I can do this easlily by defining multiple daemons in my pom

```
<daemon>
   <id>Web</id>
```

What I want to overcome is the constant repetition of shared configuration between sizes as they are essentially the same apart from some sizing arguments 
So I want to define an override properties file that will have all the default but the daemon definitions in my pom will have the unique sizing configuration

Comment: Can you take a look here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAPPASM-216 if this helps?

Comment: That looks like its only for the licence file